# nth-child pattern starting after a particular child

Tags: css, css-selectors, styles

How can you do an nth-child pattern like below:

```
div:nth-child(3n+1){
   background: #FF7100;
}
div:nth-child(3n+2){
   background: #FFB173;
}
div:nth-child(3n+3){
   background: #A64A00;
}
```

but to skip for instance the first child and only start this pattern after the first child. I tried chaining it like below but it did not seem to work:

```
 div:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(3n+1) {
    background: #FF7100;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:not(:first-child)` selector to skip the first-child.

```css
div:not(:first-child):nth-child(3n+1) {
  background: #FF7100;
}
div:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background: #FFB173;
}
div:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background: #A64A00;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
```

If you wanna skip first element for each style, try this

```css
div:nth-child(1) ~ div:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background: #FF7100;
}
div:nth-child(2) ~ div:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background: #FFB173;
}
div:nth-child(3) ~ div:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background: #A64A00;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pugazh's answer is the better answer, but just to explain why your initial attempt didn't work (I'm brand new, not enough rep to comment instead)

in CSS selectors, `n` starts at 0, so `nth-child(n+1)` was still selecting the 1st `(0+1)th` element, so `nth-child(n+2)` would've worked using your method